# Print alignment in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im a newbie of printing document using html, I have two tables one is for the body and the other one is for Tfoot only.The problem is it didn't correctly align my table header and table head below, Is there any expert can help me?

> One of the reason why I created another table because the tfoot display in every pages like this one
> [image]

> I want like this format in excel file

[image]

> Current output , note: even I change the width of each table header in table the size of the width is automatically change and I don't know why.

[image]

> My whole html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>print</title>
    <style type="text/css">
@media screen {
    th:nth-of-type(1),
    td:nth-of-type(1) {
    display: none;
   }
  .noPrint {}

  .titles {
    display: none;
   }
    .footer,.municipality,.certify,.numbers,.chief,.positions,.rev {
    display: none;
   }
   }
@media print {
  .noPrint {
    display: none;
  }
  .title {}
  .footer {}
  }

 .reportpage {
    page-break-before: always;
  }

@page{
    size: auto;
    margin: 25mm 25mm 25mm 25mm;  
}
body  
{ 

    margin: 0px;  
}

</style>
</head>

<button id="print_btn" class="btn btn-secondary round btn-min-width mr-1 mb-1"  onclick="printDivrao();">Print</button>
<section class="users-list-wrapper">
 
    <div class="users-list-table">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <!-- datatable start -->
                    <div class="table-responsive">

                    <section class="users-list-wrapper">
 
    <div class="users-list-table">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
          <div class="card-body">
  
            <div class="table-responsive">
  
              <table class="table" name="tablerao" id="tablerao">
                <thead>
                    <th colspan="9">
                        <div class="titles">
                          <span class="cash">Title </span><br>
                          <span class="social">Header </span><br>
                          <span class="unclaim">Sub TRitle</span><br><br>
                          <span class="unclaim">Sub Title</span><br><br>
                        
                         </div>  
                    </th>
                     </tr>
                    
                     <fieldset class="form-group position-relative has-icon-left wew">


                      <div class="form-control-position">
                          <i class="feather icon-search danger font-small-4"></i>
                      </div>
                    </fieldset>
                  <tr class="heads">
                    <th  width="1%" class="heads22" id="excludeExport">NO.</th>
                    <th  width="5%"  >Qr Code</th>
                    <th  width="10%"  class="fname">Full Name</th>
                    <th width="10%" class="fname">Barangay</th>
                    <th width="10%" class="fname">Birthdate</th>
                    <th width="10%" class="fname">Amount</th>
                    <th width="10%" class="fname">Description</th>
                    <th width="10%" class="fname">Municipality</th>
                    
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="report-content">
          
                  <tr >
                    <td id="excludeExport"></td>
                    <td>data 1</td>
                    <td>data 2</td>
                    <td>data 3 </td>
                    <td>data 4</td>
                    <td>data 5</td>
                    <td>data 6</td>
                    <td>data 7</td>
                  </tr>
                 
                </tbody>   
              </table>
              <table name="table1rao" id="table1rao" >
                <tfoot >
                  <col width="100px" />
                  <col width="100px" />
                  <col width="100px" />
                  <col width="100px" />
                  <col width="100px" />
                  <col width="100px" />
                  <col width="100px" />
                  <col width="100px" />
                  <col width="100px" />

                  <tr >
                    <th class="tfoots" colspan="1">Total</th>
                    <th class="tfoots"></th>
                    <th class="tfoots"><span id="count_tbl_signatories"></span></th>
                    <th class="tfoots" > </th>
                    <th class="tfoots" ></th>
                    <th class="tfoots">Total amount</th>
                    <th class="tfoots" ></th>
                    <th class="tfoots"></th>
                  </tr> 
                    <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                      
                    </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th >Prepared By</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Recommendig Aprroval</th>
                    <th></th>
                     <th></th>
                    <th>Approved By</th>
                  </tr> 
                   <tr>
                    <th >Names</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Name 2</th>
                    <th></th>
                     <th></th>
                    <th>Name 3</th>
                  </tr> 

                  <tr>
                    <th >Position1</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th> Position2</th>
                    <th></th>
                     <th></th>
                    <th>Position3</th>
                  </tr> 
              </tfoot>
            </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </section>


</body>





<script type="text/javascript">


  $(document).ready(function(){

    var table_count = ($("#tablerao > tbody > tr").length)
    document.getElementById("count_table").innerHTML = "Result "+table_count
    document.getElementById("count_tbl").innerHTML = "Result "+table_count
    document.getElementById("count_tbl_signatories").innerHTML =table_count
    $("#btnExport").click(
            function () {
              var tempTable = $("#table").html();
               $("#table #excludeExport").remove();
                tableToExcel('table','DATA','SAP_DATA');
                $("#table").html(tempTable);
            }            
        );
    })

  function printDivrao() { 
    let tbl = document.getElementById('tablerao');
    let tbl1 = document.getElementById('table1rao');    
    let footer = tbl1.getElementsByTagName('tfoot')[0];
    footer.style.display = 'table-row-group';
    tbl1.removeChild(footer);
    tbl1.appendChild(footer);    
    let title = document.querySelector('.titles');
    let newTitle = title.cloneNode(true);
    newTitle.style.textAlign = "center";
    newTitle.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    tbl.prepend(newTitle);
    title.remove();    
    var divToPrint = document.getElementById('tablerao');
    var divToPrint1 = document.getElementById('table1rao');
    var htmlToPrint = '' +
    '<style type="text/css">' +
    '.titles  {' +
    'font-family:Calibri, san-serif;' +
    'font-weight: 550;' +
    'font-size: 16px;' +
    '}' +
    
    '.id_no {' +
    'padding:1px;' +
    'margin-right: 350px;' +
    '}' +
  
    '.reportpage  {' +
    'page-break-before: always;' +
    '}' +    
    '.municipality {' +
    'font-weight: 550;' +
    'font-family:Calibri, san-serif;' +
    'font-size: 14px;' +
    'text-align: left;' +        
    '}' +
   
    '.totals  {' +
    'font-family:Calibri, san-serif;' +
    'font-weight: 550;' +
    'width:600px;' +
    'padding 5px;' +
    'font-size: 16px;' +    
    '}' +  

    '.tfoots  {' +
    'font-family:Calibri, san-serif;' +
    'font-weight: 550;' +

    'padding 5px;' +
    'font-size: 16px;' + 
    'border: 1px solid;' +  
    '}' +  

    '.footer  {' +
    'font-family:Calibri, san-serif;' +
    'font-weight: 550;' +
    'text-align: left;' +
    'font-size: 16px;' +
    'border: 16px;' +

    '}' +    
 
    'table td,.heads {' +
    'border:1px solid #000000;' +
    'padding:8px;' +
    'font-family:Calibri, san-serif;'+
    'font-size: 16px;' +
    'width: 300px;' +
    'height: 50px;' +
    '}' +

    '.fname {' +
    'border:1px solid #000000;' +
    'padding:8px;' +
    'font-family:Calibri, san-serif;'+
    'font-size: 16px;' +
    '}' +
    
   '.heads22 {' +
    'border:1px solid #000000;' +
    'padding:10px;' +
    'font-family:Calibri, san-serif;'+
    'font-size: 16px;' +

  'text-align: center;' +
    '}' +
          
    'tbody tr  {' +
    'counter-increment: noElm;' +
    '}' +
        
    '.lenss {' +
    'padding-left:80px;' +
    'font-size: 16px;' +
    '}' +
        
    'td:nth-of-type(1):before {' +
    'content: counter(noElm);' +
    '}' +
        
    'th:nth-of-type(1),td:nth-of-type(1) {' +
    'display: table-cell;' +
    '}' +
        
    'table  {' +
    'border-collapse: collapse;' +
    'width: 100%;' +
    '}' +
        
    '</style>';
    htmlToPrint += divToPrint.outerHTML;
    htmlToPrint += divToPrint1.outerHTML;
    newWin = window.open("");
    newWin.document.write(htmlToPrint);
    newWin.print();
    

      }      


</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't align stuff across multiple tables AFAIK. You need to put everything into one table, then it will automatically align.

Comment: I think it can achieve it using colspan?

Comment: yeah but id avoid that becuase you would need to know the width of each column, which would make dynamic sizing (like if its needs to be smaller on phone or something) much harder

Comment: One of the reason I created another table because when I print document  the tfoot display in every pages instead only display ion the last page like this one [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdOdU.png) do you have any idea? :/